# How can Multiple Users will Login in a single browser with Multiple Tabs Using Jmeter?

Tags: selenium, jmeter, performance-testing

How can Multiple Users will Login in a single browser with Multiple Tabs Using Jmeter.

```
var windowHandle = WDS.browser.getWindowHandle();
List tabs = new List(WDS.browser.getWindowHandles());
WDS.log.info(tabs.length());
WDS.browser.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0));
WDS.browser.switchTo().window(mainWindowHandle);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, each JMeter thread (virtual user) you define in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) (or [Custom Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups)) will kick off **its own browser instance**, it is not possible to attach to a running browser with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/).

The only way you can achieve this is using [Remote Driver Config](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins-webdriver/blob/master/RemoteDriverConfig.wiki#remote-driver-config) pointing to the [Selenium Grid](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/grid/) so the code you use in the WebDriver Sampler will be executed at all the nodes connected to the Grid at the same time, however it will be the same code (the same user, not different ones)

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)